# Keyboard Light on Lenovo Y700

Tags: laptop, keyboard

I have a Lenovo Y700, and i know there is a function that turns on the light in my keyboard. But how do i do it?

<kbd>Fn</kbd> + <kbd>Space</kbd> doesn't work.

Comment: It looks like on the pictures if you google the name. And when i turn it on, the keyboard is lights. its called Lenovo Ideapad Y700

Comment: Do you have correct drivers?

Comment: How do i know that?

Comment: http://support.lenovo.com/gb/en/products/laptops-and-netbooks/ideapad-y-series-laptops/y700-15isk?tabName=Downloads&linkTrack=Mast:SubNav:Support:Drivers%20and%20Software%7CDrivers%20and%20Software&beta=false

Answer (score -1):

Lenovo has a "Lenovo Settings" app on Windows under "Lenovo Apps".
-When Settings Opens Click the keyboard & mouse icon labeled "input"
-Then Under "Keyboard Backlight" click on the "ON" button.

n1c0